# Why use Passenger with Apache?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, passenger

Why phusion passenger is used along with apache server for a rails application ?

What's the advantage of using it ? Cant we manage alone with apache server ?

Comment: A decent discussion on this topic here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3532946/385532

Answer (score 1, accepted):

passenger phusion is what was known mod_rails, it is the same as mod_php you use to run php scripts with Apache.

Apache by default does not support processing of ruby code so you have to use a module for it.